# implementing a 301 redirect using the htaccess file in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a wordpress blog installed in a Subfolder (blog), i need to 301 redirect the **home page** of the blog to the **home page** of the domain (https://example.com/blog/ to https://example.com/), i have added the line below but it didn't work

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.com/
```

I have also tried this :

```
RewriteRule / https://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you try this code below and add it to your htaccess file from the directory of your **blog** folder and see if it works:

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^.*$ / [R=301,L]
```

Source: https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/quick-htaccess-redirect-from-subfolder.1155735/

I hope this one works!

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer and upvote if you feel it was useful to you. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: The subdomain is not accessible through https://blog.example.com, i should have called it a folder (blog) not a subdomain

Comment: Thanks for sharing that! I check for other resource.

Note that this one should be added in your htaccess from your blog folder.

Resource: https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/quick-htaccess-redirect-from-subfolder.1155735/

I hope this one works!


Try this: 


RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [R=301,L]

Comment: can u update your code?