# Wordpress Multisite subdirectory to be main site

Tags: wordpress, migration, subdirectory, multisite

I have a wordpress multisite with 2 sites - `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/new-site` .
I have been developing the new site while keeping the old one alive.

I now want to make the subdirectory subsite the main site, so when a user navigates to `www.example.com` - the content of `www.example.com/new` is shown.

What is my best way of doing this? Is it redirection ? I am hesitant to override the old site and export the site from subdirectory and import into the root directory.

Any help appreciated thanks!

Comment: Since you're hesistant to override the old site then a redirection would be best option

Comment: I posted an answer how to redirect your /new-site to your main site. Feel free to let me know if how it went!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you add the below to your htaccess file from the directory of your `/new` folder and see if it works:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [R=301,L]
```

This one works previously. Source: [implementing a 301 redirect using the htaccess file in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76953832/implementing-a-301-redirect-using-the-htaccess-file-in-wordpress/76954417#76954417)

Comment: I hope this helps and useful to you!

Comment: Thanks @cnavar for your help. :) I checked the files and I only seem to have one htacess file which is in root ?

Comment: You can create a new .htaccess file for your subdirectory /new. 
Once created, select the newly created .htaccess file > right-click > edit. Then add the code that I added in my answer to your .htaccess file.

Comment: You may not be using namecheap but you can use this as reference on how to create new .htaccess file for your subdirectory:
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9410/29/how-to-set-up-rules-and-redirects-in-htaccess/#redirect

Comment: I hope that this answers your question and you find the information useful.